# Meaning of "You missed it by just a hare"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

What does the sentence "You missed it by just a hare" mean, in this context:

Think these are rabbits?
**You missed it by just a hare**

If the context is about rabbit. What are the possible meanings of the bold sentence?

Comment: -1  spelled 'hair'

Comment: The writer is making a pun on the homonyms "hair" and "hare." I'm imagining that the reader is seeing pictures of animals that look like rabbits, but they missed ("by a hair") that these apparent rabbits are not actually rabbits.

Comment: rajah9, you should incorporate that in your answer, since it should address the hare/rabbit thing.

Comment: Good point, @MichaelHarvey. I have incorporated a pun alert in my answer.

Comment: It's a PUN!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: 
The writer is making a pun on the homophones "hair" and "hare." (I'm imagining that the reader is seeing a picture of animals that look like rabbits. But these apparent rabbits are not actually rabbits. The reader's perception was off "by a hair.")

---

I think the correct phrase is "by a hair" or "by a whisker."

[By a whisker](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/by-a-whisker) at Cambridge Dictionary means "by a very small amount."

So if you missed by a hair or by a whisker, you missed by a very small amount.

Comment: Also, homophones.

Comment: @Lambie, I have changed my edit. You are correct: "hair" and "hare" are homophones (=words pronounced the same with different meanings).